# CiviDiscount not working properly

Tags: contributions

The Disount code is no longer showing up in the front end of a contribution page.
It does show up when trying to add a contribution thourhg the admin the discount code does show up.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling again,

I recently upgraded to 4.6.10 not sure if that is when it stopped working.

Any ideas, what the problem could be???

Thanks for the input

Comment: I am experiencing the same behaviour. Discounts do not work on contribution pages. I am on CiviDiscount 3.1 CiviCRM 4.6.9 and latest Drupal.

Comment: I Unsitalled and reainsalled and it now works.